# Emploi du mot "iceberg"

Tags: anglais, anglicismes

Je lis un ouvrage sur la physique de classes prépas. L'énoncé commence par :

> Considérons un iceberg de volume total V flottant sur l'eau. Soit v le volume de partie émergée. (...)

Peut-on utiliser le mot *iceberg* en français même si l'interlocuteur ne parle pas anglais ?

Comment: Iceberg ayant été francisé il y a de cela des lustres ( subst-masc in TLF, Académie 8,...) je ne vois pas bien où serait le problème.

Comment: @aCOSwt Et la prononciation est à l'anglaise ou à la française ? Cela dépend du publique (anglophones ou pas) ? Merci !

Comment: Ha bhé... indépendamment du public, je me vois mal lire ce truc en disant "volioume totel Vi"... ergo... iceberg en prononciation F comme tout le reste des mots français de l'enoncé... oeuf corse!

Comment: @aCOSwt J'ai voulu dire :  \is.bɛʁɡ\ ou \ajs.bɛʁɡ\ ? Wiki ne le précise pas.

Comment: Le seul synonyme mentionné par le wiktionnaire *torose* n'apparaît même pas dans ngrams pour faire une comparaison : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=iceberg%2Ctorose&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ciceberg%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @aCOSwt À propos j'ai trouvé un mot désuet (pourquoi ?) torose !

Comment: @Evpok Merci. Je l'ai vu moi aussi quand tu as écris ton ton commentaire.

Comment: @Evpok En effet même Littré n'en parle pas : https://www.littre.org/recherche?mot=torose Voici le lemme wiktionary : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/torose

Comment: Le TLFi donne \is.bɛʁɡ\ et \ajs.bɛʁɡ\ ; donc libre à vous de choisir.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu qu'/ajsbɛrg/ en Belgique, mais la prononciation avec un /i/ resterait vivante dans les autres pays francophones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fondé sur les commentaires :

1. Le mot iceberg a été francisé il y a des lustres
   (subst-masc in TLF, Académie 8,...).
2. Les deux prononciations \is.bɛʁɡ\ et \ajs.bɛʁɡ\ sont acceptables.
3. Le seul synonyme mentionné par le wiktionnaire, *torose*, n'apparaît même pas dans ngrams pour faire une comparaison.
4. Littré ne parle pas de *torose*. Voici une [citation](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/torose) où le mot apparaît :

> *Ce genre de torose se forme au commencement de l'hiver, ou bien en automne quand la surface de la mer est encore coupée par de vastes polinas.* — (de Wrangell, *Voyage au nord de la Sibérie*, Éd. d'Amyot, Paris 1843)

5. Selon le [wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/torose), le mot *torose* est rare et désuet.
6. En Belgique au moins, la prononciation dominante est \ajs.bɛʁɡ\.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu \is.bɛʁɡ\ de ma vie, je recommande fortement de prononcer  \ajs.bɛʁɡ\.